# These DLL Files are Missing in My Project or Unity Folder

Tags: unity-game-engine

These DLL files are missing in my project or Unity folder.

How can I find these files again? I reopened my project with a different name and it didn't fix it. I deleted the Library folder, it was recreated, it still didn't fix. I deleted Unity and reinstalled it, still didn't fix it. What should I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6huEc.png)

Comment: Don’t post pictures of code. Ever.   I don’t see any using statements in this?

Comment: @BugFinder The dll file in the Library\ScriptAssemblies package does not exist. I'm deleting the library folder, it doesn't fix against the reworking. Unity doesn't improve in 2022 and 2021 versions, but it doesn't.

Comment: @BugFinder I added Unity as UnityEditor and UnityEngine but it is not resolved. I can't access the visible classes in the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed one of the missing DLLs, namely Terrain Tools, via Package Manager. Then all the other missing DLLs were found. Pretty odd.